# Export a string in Java to CSV

Tags: java, string, csv, export-to-csv

How to export a string in Java to a csv file having this format using only one column.

This is what i am expecting:

```
                Column 1    
Row 1:     string1,string2,string3  
Row 2:     string4, string5, string6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried googling for 3rd-party libraries that serialize to CSV?

Comment: How it is single column. As columns are separated by commas, i see three columns in each row.

Comment: open an outputstream and write to it.

Comment: There is absolutly no need for third party libs to serialize to csv

Comment: csv -  comma-separated values file in tabular format, hereyour string1, string2, string3 that means they are separate columns for csv not 1 column

Comment: Of course you don't need a 3rd-party lib for serializing.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

In the code below you provide a List of elements. Each element contains the info for one line of the csv file.
The StringBuilder is used to create the String for one line, which then is output at once to the file.

```
public void writeCsvFile(List elements, String fileName) throws IOException {    
     BufferedWriter csvFile = null;
     String delim = ",";
     try {
             csvFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        new FileOutputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
             for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                 StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
                 Elements elem = elements.get(i);
                 buf.append(elem.info1).append(delim);
                 buf.append(elem.info2).append(delim);
                 buf.append(elem.info3);
                 csvFile.write(buf.toString());
                 csvFile.newLine();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (csvFile != null) {
                    csvFile.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // empty
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have to "escape" the commas so the CSV reader won't interrpret them as columns delimiters.

If you wrap your row values in quotes then the commas should be ignored as delimeters

This will give you 3 columns

```
Value1,Value2,Value3
```

This should give you 1 column with the entire string as a single value

```
"Value1,Value2,Value3"
```